# Сколько всего аватаров по умолчанию?

Tags: поддержка, аватар-пользователя, аватар-по-умолчанию

Если не пользователь не поставит себе аватар, то система даёт ему аватар по умолчанию - коврик с узором какого-либо цвета.

**Вопрос**: сколько всего таких аватаров? И могут может ли система дать двум пользователям одинаковый аватар?

Comment: используется сервис https://ru.gravatar.com/

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял из [этого поста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated), аватары по умолчанию генерируются с помощью хитроумных алгоритмов на основе:

- адреса электронной почты, если пользователь его указал;
- последнего IP-адреса, с которого заходил пользователь, **если электронная почта НЕ указана**. Интересно, что в этом случае аватар [может меняться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37763/1346379), если зайти с другого IP.

То есть эти аватары (идентиконы) - визуальные представления IP-адресов и названий e-mail'ов.